# Javascript var to php after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a table where it displays the ID and on click I get the ID.
I then used Json and sent it to page editReport.php where i want to get to the variable to view the report I wish to edit. Can I get it to a php variable on the editReport page. I have used JSON to populate a javascript variable with PHP but cant find a way to get javascript to PHP.

```
   //Reports.PHP
   function myFunction() {
   $(".reportId").click(function () {

            var selectedReportId = $(this).text();

            //alert to test if gets ID from click
            alert(selectedReportId);

            selectedReportId = JSON.stringify(selectedReportId);
            localStorage.setItem('selectedReportId', selectedReportId);

             window.location = "editReport.php";
        });
  }
```

this here is the page the var is sent to. Any possible way to get that variable into a PHP var

```
   //editReports
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction() {
alert("hi");

var selectedReportId = localStorage.getItem('selectedReportId');
if (selectedReportId) selectedReportId = JSON.parse(selectedReportId);


alert(selectedReportId);


 $.post('editReport.php', {variable: selectedReportId});
 }



<?php
//make this variable populated from the javascript
$varID = $_POST['variable'];
echo "$varID";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query string like so:

`window.location = "editReport.php?selectedReportId="+selectedReportId`

Then in php retrieve that variable using:

`$selectedReportId = $_GET['selectedReportId'];`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use POST or GET, you could also do the following in editReport.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedReportId = localStorage.getItem('selectedReportId');
document.write(selectedReportId);
</script>

<?php
$offset  = ob_get_clean();
$cl      =  strip_tags($offset);
$pattern = "/document\.write\('([^)]*)'\)/";
preg_match($pattern, $cl, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
?>
```

This should pull it into PHP via the screen output.

Hope this helps!